# Enumeration of sqrt signs

Tags: enumerate, sqrt

I need to enumerate \sqrt signs as shown in the picture below
but have no idea how to do it.
I wonder if anyone could help. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 12):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,mathtools}
\stackMath
\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
\setstackgap{S}{0pt}
\newcounter{sqrti}
\newcommand\esqrt[2][\litsqrti]{%
  \ifx\litsqrti#1%
    \stepcounter{sqrti}%
    \edef\litsqrti{\thesqrti}%
  \fi
  \stackunder{\displaystyle\sqrt{#2}}{\smash{%
  \belowbaseline[3pt]{\scriptscriptstyle~\mathclap{#1}}}}
}
\newcommand\resetesqrt{\setcounter{sqrti}{-1}}
\begin{document}
\[
\resetesqrt
\esqrt{p\pm\esqrt{p\pm\dots\pm\esqrt[n-2]{p}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

**SUPPLEMENT**

In the prior code, there is a 3pt gap set between the bottom of the surd and the index.  As the surd depth changes, so will the depth of the index.

The OP asks if the indices can be aligned vertically.  The answer is yes; however, here, the depth must be defined relative to the baseline.  Choosing the proper depth could vary with each use case, depending on the depth of the associated square-root surds.

Thus, I provide `\esqrtdp` to define that depth, set here to 13pt.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,mathtools}
\stackMath
\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
\setstackgap{L}{0pt}
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}
\newcounter{sqrti}
\newcommand\esqrt[2][\litsqrti]{%
  \ifx\litsqrti#1%
    \stepcounter{sqrti}%
    \edef\litsqrti{\thesqrti}%
  \fi
  \stackunder{\displaystyle\sqrt{#2}}{\smash{%
  \belowbaseline[\esqrtdp]{\scriptscriptstyle~\mathclap{#1}}}}%
}
\newcommand\resetesqrt{\setcounter{sqrti}{-1}}
\newcommand\esqrtdp{13pt}
\begin{document}
\[
\resetesqrt
\esqrt{p\pm\esqrt{p\pm\dots\pm\esqrt[n-2]{p}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could it be possible to align vertically the enumerating numbers 0, 1, ... ?

Comment: @projetmbc Please see my **SUPPLEMENT**